Flutter app crashes: Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground()
I am using flutter background service to run a beacon scan in the background and in the foreground when the app is disconnected.
I get the folowing response when the app crashes. The app only occurs when i first close the app and then open it again. And when i open it after the crash then it opens normally
I am ussing flutter_background_service.
And flutter_blue_plus
This problem seems to occur from the android 14 os version.
I seems to occur while the foreground service is trying to start
after reopening the app.
Any suggestions for a possible solution?
D/[FBP-Android](17180): [FBP] onDetachedFromEngine
D/BluetoothAdapter(17180): isLeEnabled(): ON
D/[FBP-Android](17180): [FBP] disconnectAllDevices(onDetachedFromEngine)
D/AndroidRuntime(17180): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime(17180): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(17180): Process: com.dptechnics.test.main_app, PID: 17180
E/AndroidRuntime(17180): android.app.RemoteServiceException$ForegroundServiceDidNotStartInTimeException: Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground(): ServiceRecord{e156910 u0 com.dptechnics.test.main_app/id.flutter.flutter_background_service.BackgroundService c:com.dptechnics.test.main_app}
E/AndroidRuntime(17180):        at android.app.ActivityThread.generateForegroundServiceDidNotStartInTimeException(ActivityThread.java:2243)
E/AndroidRuntime(17180):        at android.app.ActivityThread.throwRemoteServiceException(ActivityThread.java:2214)
E/AndroidRuntime(17180):        at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mthrowRemoteServiceException(Unknown Source:0)
E/AndroidRuntime(17180):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2520)
E/AndroidRuntime(17180):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
E/AndroidRuntime(17180):        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:232)
E/AndroidRuntime(17180):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:317)
E/AndroidRuntime(17180):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8592)
E/AndroidRuntime(17180):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(17180):        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:580)
E/AndroidRuntime(17180):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:878)
E/AndroidRuntime(17180): Caused by: android.app.StackTrace: Last startServiceCommon() call for this service was made here
E/AndroidRuntime(17180):        at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1953)
E/AndroidRuntime(17180):        at android.app.ContextImpl.startForegroundService(ContextImpl.java:1907)
E/AndroidRuntime(17180):        at android.content.ContextWrapper.startForegroundService(ContextWrapper.java:832)
E/AndroidRuntime(17180):        at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat$Api26Impl.startForegroundService(ContextCompat.java:1128)
E/AndroidRuntime(17180):        at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startForegroundService(ContextCompat.java:700)
E/AndroidRuntime(17180):        at id.flutter.flutter_background_service.FlutterBackgroundServicePlugin.start(FlutterBackgroundServicePlugin.java:83)
E/AndroidRuntime(17180):        at id.flutter.flutter_background_service.FlutterBackgroundServicePlugin.onMethodCall(FlutterBackgroundServicePlugin.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(17180):        at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:267)     
E/AndroidRuntime(17180):        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:292)
E/AndroidRuntime(17180):        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:319)
E/AndroidRuntime(17180):        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:12)        
E/AndroidRuntime(17180):        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:959)
E/AndroidRuntime(17180):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
E/AndroidRuntime(17180):        ... 6 more
I/Process (17180): Sending signal. PID: 17180 SIG: 9

My android manifest
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true" />

     <!-- New Bluetooth permissions in Android 12
     https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/features/bluetooth-permissions -->
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
 
     <!-- legacy for Android 11 or lower -->
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" android:maxSdkVersion="30"/>
 
 
     <!-- legacy for Android 9 or lower -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" android:maxSdkVersion="28" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <!--Add this Permissions-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_LOCATION"/>
    <!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_CONNECTED_DEVICE" /> -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_DATA_SYNC"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_STACK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_USE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

    <!-- foregroundServiceType: dataSync -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_DATA_SYNC" />
<application
...
 <service
            android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ForegroundService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:stopWithTask="false"/>

      <service
          android:name="id.flutter.flutter_background_service.BackgroundService"
          android:foregroundServiceType="location"/>

  <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ActionBroadcastReceiver" />
        <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver" />
        <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

My main.dart
const notificationId = 888;
const notificationChannelId = 'Main app';

void main() async {
  ///Set the bluetooth log level for the bluetooth connection
  FlutterBluePlus.setLogLevel(LogLevel.none, color: true);
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await initializeNotifications();
  await requestPermissions();
  await initLocalPrefs();

  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
  ]);
  await requestPermissionsBluetooth();

  await initBeaconScanTask();

  runApp(MainApp());
}


///Request the permission of the local notification.
Future<void> requestPermissions() async {
  bool? granted = false;
  if (Platform.isIOS) {
    granted = await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            IOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.requestPermissions(
          alert: true,
          badge: true,
          sound: true,
        );
  } else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    granted = await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
            .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
                AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
            ?.areNotificationsEnabled() ??
        false;

    if (!granted) {
      granted = await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
          .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
              AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()!
          .requestNotificationsPermission();
    }
  }

  notificationsEnabled = granted!;

  logger.d("The notifications are enabled $notificationsEnabled");
}

Future<bool> requestPermissionsBluetooth() async {
  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    var status = await [
      Permission.bluetooth,
      Permission.bluetoothScan,
      Permission.bluetoothConnect,
      Permission.locationAlways,
      Permission.locationWhenInUse,
    ].request();

    // Check if all permissions are granted
    return status.values.every((element) => element.isGranted);
  }
  return false;
}


Future<void> initializeNotifications() async {
  const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
    notificationChannelId,
    'Beacon service',
    description:
        'This channel is used for important notifications.', // description
    importance: Importance.low, // importance must be at low or higher level
  );

  const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
      AndroidInitializationSettings(ImageConstant.imgNotIcon);
  final DarwinInitializationSettings initializationSettingsDarwin =
      DarwinInitializationSettings(
    requestAlertPermission: true,
    requestBadgePermission: false,
    requestSoundPermission: false,
    onDidReceiveLocalNotification:
        (int id, String? title, String? body, String? payload) async {},
  );
  final InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
    android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
    iOS: initializationSettingsDarwin,
  );
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
    initializationSettings,
    onDidReceiveNotificationResponse:
        (NotificationResponse notificationResponse) {},
  );

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
          AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);
}

Future<void> initBeaconScanTask() async {
  logger.d("Initializing the beacon scan in the background and foreground");
  try {
    final service = FlutterBackgroundService();

    await service.configure(
      androidConfiguration: AndroidConfiguration(
        autoStart: true,
        onStart: beaconScanTask,
        notificationChannelId: "This a notification for softener",
        isForegroundMode: true,
        autoStartOnBoot: true,
      ),
      iosConfiguration: IosConfiguration(
        autoStart: true,
        onForeground: beaconScanTask,
        onBackground: iosBackgroundBeaconScanTask,
      ),
    );
    // if (!(await service.isRunning())) {

    service.startService();
    // }
    logger.d("Service started ");
  } catch (e) {
    logger.e(
        "An error occurred when starting service. (${e.hashCode} : ${e.toString()})");
  }
}

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<bool> iosBackgroundBeaconScanTask(ServiceInstance service) async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized();
  //TODO
  return true;
}

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void beaconScanTask(ServiceInstance service) {
  // Set listeners for Android service instance
  if (service is AndroidServiceInstance) {
    service.setAsForegroundService();
    service.setForegroundNotificationInfo(
      title: "Scanning for softener",
      content: "This service is scanning for softener beacons",
    );

    service.on('setAsForeground').listen((event) {
      logger.i("BLE scanner is running as foreground service");
      service.setAsForegroundService();
    });

    service.on('setAsBackground').listen((event) {
      logger.i("BLE scanner is running as background service");
      service.setAsBackgroundService();
    });
  }

  service.on('stopService').listen((event) {
    logger.i("BLE background service was stopped by OS request");
    service.stopSelf();
  });

  backgroundBeaconScan();
}

I have tried changing the sdk in the build.gradle
android {
compileSdk 34
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

defaultConfig {
minSdkVersion 29
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName

I have added the channel id but this does nothing.
